# Is it possible in nHibernate to set a property NOT to map to a column in a table while other properties of the class does

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mapping, subclassing

I am having a class and all properties but one mapped to the corresponding table columns. Now the one remaining property i want to set to some value when nhibernate creates the new instance of the class.

eg.

```
    --only two columns

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
        [key] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL) 
    --..........


    public class Entity
    {
    public int key {get;set;}
    public string EntityType {get;set;}
    }

    public class Person : Entity
    {
    public string Name {get;set;} 
    }


and i have maps
            Map(Person => Person.key).Not.Nullable();
            Map(Person => Person.Name).Not.Nullable();  
            // i don't want a map for EntityType
```

here I want for an instance of Person, EntityType should be always set to a custom string, "Person". other properties are usually mapped to the corresponding columns of Person Table.

Is that possible ?

Comment: How about setting the EntityType property from the constructor of the inherited class?
Or perhaps just public string EntityType 
        {
            get { return this.GetType().Name; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the `EntityType` property in the `Person` constructor with your desired value.
You don't need to map it.

```
public class Person : Entity
{
    public Person()
    {
        EntityType = "Person";
    }
}
```